# Error al implementar control definido por usuario a otro formulario

Tags: c#, sql-server, windows-forms, excepciones, usercontrol

espero esten bien.

Estoy desarrollando un proyecto con windows forms en visual studio 2017 en c# con conexión a base de datos en sql 2018. El desarrollo es en POO y en capas.

Todo el desarrollo de mi control iba bien, hasta que lo agregue a la caja de herramientas para poder utilizarlo en otros formularios, ya que me muestra el siguiente mensaje de error(Adjunto en imagen).

Al parecer es un error relacionado con el sql helper, cabe mencionar que no me había sucedido anteriormente con ningún otro control Espero me puedan ayudar, saludos y gracias.(Adjunto código del control )

El problema en este caso es que yo no sé qué parte es importante y qué no lo es, y pongo lo que he hecho hasta ese momento. Puede que sobre código, pero no creo que falte explicar nada, y si no sé qué parte del código sobra supongo que es mejor pecar de precavido. Gracias por sus respuestas.

```
namespace Controles
{
    public partial class ctl_DomicilioCP : UserControl
    {
        SIO.BLL.Colonia colonias = new SIO.BLL.Colonia();
        SIO.BLL.Calles calles = new SIO.BLL.Calles();
        SIO.BLL.TipoAsentamiento asentamiento = new SIO.BLL.TipoAsentamiento();

        public ctl_DomicilioCP()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

   
        private void ctl_DomicilioCP_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            IList<SIO.Model.ColoniaInfo> ColoniaInfo = colonias.TraerColonia(SIO.BLL.InformacionGeneral.conexionInfo);
            cboeColonias.DataSource = ColoniaInfo;


            cboeColonias.ValueMember = "col_Indice";
            cboeColonias.DisplayMember = "col_Nombre";

            IList<SIO.Model.CallesInfo> CallesInfo = calles.TraerCalles(SIO.BLL.InformacionGeneral.conexionInfo);
            cboeCalle.DataSource = CallesInfo;


            cboeCalle.ValueMember = "cal_Indice";
            cboeCalle.DisplayMember = "cal_Nombre";


            IList<SIO.Model.TipoAsentamientoInfo> TipoAsentamientoInfo = asentamiento.TraerTipoAsentamiento(SIO.BLL.InformacionGeneral.conexionInfo);
            cboeAsentamiento.DataSource = TipoAsentamientoInfo;
            cboeAsentamiento.ValueMember = "tase_Indice";
            cboeAsentamiento.DisplayMember = "tase_Descripcion";

        }
    }
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]